# CPU/GPU Monitering. (Tempature, current speed, etc) in C#

Tags: c#, .net, system-monitoring

I'm looking for a way to monitor system statistics.

### Here are my main points of interest:

- CPU Tempature
- CPU speed (Cycles per second)
- CPU Load (Idle percent)
- GPU Tempature

### Some other points of interest:

- Memory usage
- Network Load (Traffic Up/Down)

My ultimate goal is to write an application that can be used for easily running in the backround, and allow setting many events for certain actions, example: `When processer temp gets to 56C -> Do _Blank_` etc.

### So this leaves me two main points.

1. Is there a framework already out there for this sort of thing?
2. If No to #1, How can I go about doing this?

### Footnote

If the code is in another .net language it's okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I figured out how to get my usage! 1 down, 3 to go.

CPU Usage:

```
using (PerformanceCounter pc = new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "_Total"))
{
    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(pc.NextValue());
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582(VS.85).aspx)